# Automatically zooming in on highcharts after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Does anyone know how to automatically zoom into a portion of a chart after it finishes loading? I have a lot of timeseries data but the most important info is to the right. I'd still like all the data to be available but only the most recent 7 days in view zoomed in.

What I would like to simulate is a user click-dragging for the 7 latest days on my chart. So if anyone knows how to manually trigger that event, it's probably what I'd like to do.

Here is a sample chart from jsfiddle that has the normal zooming functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5q8H/50/

I have a few other ideas of how this could be done, but I think what I want is the best way to go about it.

Other ideas:

1) Only load the last 7 days, put a fake 'Reset Zoom' button that then loads the whole data series afterwards

2) Look into that sister product [StockCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) that's in Beta right now. It seems to have a bunch of preset range displays which would be cool to have too. I'm not sure how much of my existing code I'd have to change though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the setExtremes function to change the zoom.  http://jsfiddle.net/quVda/382/

For a timeseries chart with day-by-day information, you need to use the UTC representation of the date:

```
var d = new Date();
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
    Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() - 7),
    Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
```

Comment: Awesome! I set this up to happen in the load event handler and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: The only issue is it doesn't make the Reset Zoom Button appear. Anyway to use the default one like you would have if you zoomed in normally?

Comment: Updated the fiddle based on the highcharts source.  You can add an item to the chart's toolbar: http://jsfiddle.net/quVda/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, Dennis! Works like a charm! <3

Comment: 1) the jsfiddle doesn't show anything but a button "clickme", 2) the "toolbar" doesn't seem to be available any more

Comment: @sjngm Thanks for letting me know - it should work now

Comment: A simpler way to show the zoom button after programmatically calling setExtremes() is: chart.showResetZoom(). See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028504/launch-highcharts-zooming-programmatically-after-a-selection/19030897#19030897.

Answer (score 5):

Updated official fiddle for solution, guys: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setextremes/

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1),
            Date.UTC(2007, 11, 31)
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option if you try

```
var max_in = 100; //the highest y value you have in your series data;
var min_in = 41 ;//the lowest y value you have in your series data;

yaxis=this.yAxis[0];
yaxis.options.max = max_in;
yaxis.options.min = min_in;
```