# Set x-axis range in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple time series that do not have the same starting/ending points. I want to fix a starting point and a ending point in x-axis, I tried something like:

```
    xAxis: {
        min: new Date('2000/10/22'),
        max: new Date('2010/10/22'),
    },
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/34CZK/)

But it does not work. Btw, the document on highcharts website has a wrong link for `min` in [xAis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.min).

Comment: The setExtremes function may be able to help?  Check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194249/automatically-zooming-in-on-highcharts-after-loading

Answer (score 14):

Min and max should be timestamps, not date objects.

Proper code:

```
    xAxis: {
        min: new Date('2000/10/22').getTime(),
        max: new Date('2010/10/22').getTime(),
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34CZK/3/

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to change the date range in the navigation bar? In your example, it starts at 2003-09-20, not 2000/10/22.

Comment: Just remove 'selected' option.

Comment: After removing `selected`, the starting date is set to `2000/10/22`; however when I move the navigator, the starting date is reset to the starting date of the time series..